# Any difference between these two regular expression?

Tags: regex

```
abc([^\r\n]*) // 0 or more

abc([^\r\n]+)? // 1 or more, but it's optional
```

In Java. They look exactly the same to me.

Comment: They look the same to me as well.

Comment: In case of `abc` the first one will store an empty string to the first capturing group, the second one won't store this group, however I'm not familiar enough with java to know what happens when you try to access group 1. Note that in other regex flavours, where conditional matching (PCRE, Boost, .net etc.) or replacing (Boost) is supported, this can make a huge difference. Oh and Delphi has problems accessing not-matched named capturing groupes.

Comment: Wow. I just had to test it and I guess I posted the wrong answer. https://regex101.com/r/H6nkxD/1 shows that different parsers indeed behave differently regarding the group ```(...)?```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small difference between the two. The following [code](http://ideone.com/djdiQ9)

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class Example
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String text = "abc";
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("abc([^\\r\\n]*)");
        Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(text);
        if (m1.find()) {
            System.out.println("MatchCount: " + m1.groupCount());
            System.out.println("Group 1: " + m1.group(1));
        } else {
            System.out.println("No match.");
        }
        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("abc([^\\r\\n]+)?");
        Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(text);
        if (m2.find()) {
            System.out.println("MatchCount: " + m2.groupCount());
            System.out.println("Group 1: " + m2.group(1));
        } else {
            System.out.println("No match.");
        }
    }
}
```

Gives output:

```
MatchCount: 1
Group 1: 
MatchCount: 1
Group 1: null
```

So in case of string `abc` the first regex creates a capturing group with empty content, while in the second the group is empty and thus not matched. Though I'm not that familiar with Java, I'd guess you will have to treat them a bit different.

Sidenote:

Java doesn't support conditional matching (unlike PCRE, .net, Boost and some more) and conditional replacing (unlike Boost) where this would make a huge difference. Oh and Delphi has [issues with optional named capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425123/how-to-handle-tregex-named-capture-groups-that-might-be-empty).